# Jquery Move from One Box to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to get a bit of code working on my site although it is working in JSFiddle.

I have this script in the body.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.add').click(function(){
$('#first option:selected').appendTo('#second');
});
$('.remove').click(function(){
$('#second option:selected').appendTo('#first');
});
$('.add-all').click(function(){
$('#first option').appendTo('#second');
});
$('.remove-all').click(function(){
$('#second option').appendTo('#first');
});
</script>
```

And I have this to execute the script.

```
    <div id="input14">
    <select id="first" multiple="true">
        <option value="something@something.com"> test </option>
        <option value="something@something.com"> something@something.com </option>
        <option value="something@something.com"> something@something.com </option>
        <option value="something@something.com"> something@something.com </option>
        <option value="something@something.com"> something@something.com </option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div id="button14">



        <center>
        <br />
        <button class='add'> > </button><br />
        <button class='remove'> < </button><br />
        <button class='add-all'> >>> </button><br />
        <button class='remove-all'> <<< </button>
        </center>
    </div>

    <div id="error14">

        <select id="second" multiple="true">

        </select>



    </div>
```

As I say it works in JSFiddle but not on my localhost, here is the JSFiddle setup http://jsfiddle.net/8nezD/1/

Please can somebody show me the error of my ways!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your jQuery in a document ready call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add').click(function () {
        $('#first option:selected').appendTo('#second');
    });
    $('.remove').click(function () {
        $('#second option:selected').appendTo('#first');
    });
    $('.add-all').click(function () {
        $('#first option').appendTo('#second');
    });
    $('.remove-all').click(function () {
        $('#second option').appendTo('#first');
    });
});
```

The reason it works on jsFiddle is because the site is wrapping it for you automatically.

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').click(function(){
    $('#first option:selected').appendTo('#second');
    });
    $('.remove').click(function(){
    $('#second option:selected').appendTo('#first');
    });
    $('.add-all').click(function(){
    $('#first option').appendTo('#second');
    });
    $('.remove-all').click(function(){
    $('#second option').appendTo('#first');
    });
    });
    </script>

Comment: I only had a warning about not having any type declared for the script tag. I thought JQuery didn't need a type declaring?